# grep and egrep selecting numbers

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have to find all entries of people whose zip code has “22” in it. NOTE: this should not include something like Mike Keneally whose street address includes “22”.

Here are some samples of data:

```
Bianca Jones, 612 Charles Blvd, Louisville, KY 40228
Frank V. Zappa, 6221 Hot Rats Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90125
George Duke, San Diego, CA 93241
Ruth Underwood, Mariemont, OH 42522
```

Here is the command I have so far, but I don't know why it's not working.

```
 egrep '.*[A-Z][A-Z]\s*[0-9]+[22][0-9]+$' names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

guess this is your sample names.txt

> Bianca Jones, 612 Charles Blvd, Louisville, KY 40228
>
> Frank V. Zappa, 6221 Hot Rats Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90125
>
> George Duke, San Diego, CA 93241
>
> Ruth Underwood, Mariemont, OH 42522

egrep '.*[A-Z][A-Z]\s*[0-9]+[22][0-9]+$' names.txt

your code translates to match any line satisfy this conditions:

1. `[A-Z][A-Z]` has two consecutive upper case characters
2. `\s*` zero or more space characters
3. `[0-9]+` one or more digit character
4. `[22]` a character matches either 2 or 2
5. `[0-9]+$` one or more digit characters at the end of the line

to get lines satisfying your requirement:

> zip code has “22” in it

you can do it this way:

```
egrep '[A-Z]{2}\s+[0-9]*22' names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If zip code is always the last field, you can use this `awk`

```
awk '$NF~/22/' file
Bianca Jones, 612 Charles Blvd, Louisville, KY 40228
Ruth Underwood, Mariemont, OH 42522
```